# clearInterval doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I have some problem with this code, when I click the start button everything is working as expected but when I want to stop animation with `clearInterval` it doesn’t work, just keeps looping... What I am doing wrong?

```
 var a = function() { 
     $("div").animate({height:300},"slow");
     $("div").animate({width:300},"slow");
     $("div").animate({height:100},"slow");
     $("div").animate({width:100},"slow");
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("start").click(function(){

         setInterval(a,1000);
     });

     $("stop").click(function(){
         clearInterval(a);

     });

 });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should pass a reference(which you get from `setInterval`) to `clearInterval` method to clear it. Try this

```
var intervalId;
var a = function() { 
    $("div").animate({height:300},"slow");
    $("div").animate({width:300},"slow");
    $("div").animate({height:100},"slow");
    $("div").animate({width:100},"slow");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#start").click(function(){
        intervalId = setInterval(a,1000);
    });

    $("#stop").click(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });

});
```

Comment: @Dejo - Glad it helped you, make sure to mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Wazzzy - Thats correct. I think its pseudo code but the point to understand is intervalId should be passed to clearInterval.

Comment: @DejoDekic My answer is absolutely correct and working also I had given reference link...Shankar got the points for quick answer...But mine should be accepted... At least it deserve some appreciation..

Comment: Thats not fair...I will say...Any ways I appreciate your answer @ShankarSangoli ....

Comment: Don't be angry Wazzzy i really appreciate your answer and your willingness to help newbie like myself :)

Answer (score 3):

The "setInterval()" function **returns** a value.  That's what you need to pass to "clearInterval()", not a reference to the handler.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div style="height:310px;width:310px;">
    <div id="div" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#000">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="start" value="start">
<input type="button" id="stop" value="stop">
```

**JQUERY**

var startInterval;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var a = function() { 
         $("#div").animate({height:300},"slow");
         $("#div").animate({width:300},"slow");
         $("#div").animate({height:100},"slow");
         $("#div").animate({width:100},"slow");
     }
     $("#start").click(function(){
         startInterval=setInterval(a, 2500);
     });

     $("#stop").click(function(){
         clearInterval(startInterval);
     });
});
```

Check this out for reference [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pPdbG/133/)

Comment: @Syno Update the jsfiddle link. Also edited the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
var chk =  setInterval(a,1000);
then
clearInterval(chk);
```